# Get list of Message Resource defined in struts config

Tags: java, struts-1, struts-config

I am trying to create am method to reload all the message resource defined in struts config. There are more than one message resource defined. I need a way to get all the `<message-resources>` defined in struts config.

I am using Struts 1.2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to get the list by this underlying code snippet.

```
    ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();

ModuleConfig moduleConfig = ModuleUtils
                                .getInstance()
                                .getModuleConfig(request, context);

    MessageResourcesConfig[] msgConfigArr = ModuleUtils.getInstance()
                                            .getModuleConfig(request)
                                            .findMessageResourcesConfigs();

    MessageResources[] messages= new MessageResources[msgConfigArr.length]; 
for(int i = 0; i<msgConfigArr.length;i++){
    if(msgConfigArr[i]==null)
    continue;

    messages[i] = context.getAttribute(key[i] + moduleConfig.getPrefix());
}

    return messages;
```

Hope this help Somebody.